# Why is a type of the member of the object different in a function?

Tags: scala, reflection, types, scala-reflect

Code below produces following result:

```
as member: nested: AnyRef{def x: Int; def x_=(x$1: Int): Unit}
as local: nested: Object
```

(Tested with Scala 2.12.12 and Scala 2.12.3)

Can someone explain why?

```
object Main extends App {

  def getNestedType(m: Any) = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror

    for {
      symbol <- currentMirror.classSymbol(m.getClass).toType.members
      if symbol.isTerm && !symbol.isMethod && !symbol.isModule
    } yield {
      s"{symbol.name.decodedName}: ${symbol.info}"
    }
  }

  object obj {
    var nested = new {
      var x = 0
    }
  }

  getNestedType(obj).foreach(x => println(s"as member: $x"))


  def f(): Unit = {
    object obj {
      var nested = new {
        var x = 0
      }
    }

    getNestedType(obj).foreach(x => println(s"as local: $x"))
  }

  f()

}
```

Comment: The thing can be in mixing Java reflection (`.getClass`) with Scala reflection (the rest). The pure Scala version `def getNestedType[T: TypeTag](m: T) = { for { symbol <- typeOf[T].members ...` returns `AnyRef{def x: Int; def x_=(x$1: Int): Unit}` both times.

Comment: Although `def getNestedType[T: ClassTag](m: T) = { for { symbol <- currentMirror.reflect(m).symbol.info.members ...` again shows discrepancy: `AnyRef{def x: Int; def x_=(x$1: Int): Unit}` vs. `Object`.

Comment: Connected question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64519009/how-to-recognize-an-anonymous-class-in-a-scala-macro