# How to find class parameter datatype at runtime in scala

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def getType[T: TypeTag](obj: T) = typeOf[T]

case class Thing(
  val id: Int,
  var name: String
)
val thing = Thing(1, "Apple")

val dataType = getType(thing).decl(TermName("id")).asTerm.typeSignature

dataType match {
 case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => println("I am Int")
 case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => println("String, Do some stuff")
 case _ => println("Absurd")
}
```

Not able to digest why result is `Absurd` instead of `I am int`?

My aim is to know data-type of class parameter at runtime and match it to predefined types.

Comment: What's the goal? Looks like an x/y question where you think that runtime reflection is the way to complete a goal you don't explain (while runtime reflection is rarely the only way to go, and even less the good one).

Comment: @cchantep Actually, because the question is about `Type`s similar question can be asked about compile-time reflection.

Comment: Connected https://users.scala-lang.org/t/how-to-find-and-match-parameter-datatype-at-runtime/6932

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both current `dataType` and `typeOf[Int]` are printed as `Int` but if you do `showRaw` you'll see why they don't match

```
showRaw(dataType) // NullaryMethodType(TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List()))
showRaw(typeOf[Int]) // TypeRef(ThisType(scala), scala.Int, List())
```

The thing is that just the type `Int` and the type of nullary method returning `Int` are different types.

Try to add `.resultType`

```
val dataType = getType(thing).decl(TermName("id")).asTerm.typeSignature.resultType

dataType match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => println("I am Int")
  case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => println("String, Do some stuff")
  case _ => println("Absurd")
} // I am Int
```

---

It's also worth mentioning that `.decl(TermName("id"))` returns getter symbol, it's `.decl(TermName("id "))` (with a blank space) that returns field symbol. So alternatively you can do with a blank space in the symbol name and without `.resultType`

```
val dataType = getType(thing).decl(TermName("id ")).asTerm.typeSignature
```

---

I'll add to **@TomerShetah**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65072704/5249621) that if the goal is "pattern matching" all fields of a case class then this can be done also at compile time (mostly) with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless):

```
import shapeless.Poly1
import shapeless.syntax.std.product._

object printTypes extends Poly1 {
  implicit val int: Case.Aux[Int, Unit] = at(t => println(s"I am Int: $t"))
  implicit val string: Case.Aux[String, Unit] = at(t => println(s"String, Do some stuff: $t"))
  implicit def default[V]: Case.Aux[V, Unit] = at(t => println(s"Absurd: $t"))
}
  
thing.toHList.map(printTypes)
// I am Int: 1
// String, Do some stuff: Apple
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/N4Idk4KcRumQJZE2CHC0yQ

Answer (score 1):

@Dmytrio answer is a great explanation why the reflection didn't work as you expected.

I can understand from your question, that what you are trying to do, is actually pattern match all variables you have in a case class. Please consider doing it in the following way:

```
case class Thing(id: Int, name: String)
val thing = Thing(1, "Apple")

thing.productIterator.foreach {
  case t: Int => println(s"I am Int: $t")
  case t: String => println(s"String, Do some stuff: $t")
  case t => println(s"Absurd: $t")
}
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/JB2K1fTwQLe33FFAZx97sg).